# Android studio automatically tries to update libraries?

Tags: android, gradle

In my project I have many libraries defined in `dependencies` section in `gradle`. Problem is once in a while (once/twice a day)`Android Studio` gives me errors like this when opening the project or trying to get a release output:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':TMessagesProj@armv7Debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.+.
```

My guess is it is because `build tools` is trying to check if there is an update for each library and when it doesn't find an Internet connection, it shows this error. If so, how can I change the setting in a way it doesn't have to check for updates? In other words in my project I don't need to update my libraries.

I know there is an `offline mode` that will probably do the trick! But I don't want to use this feature because it will probably disable some other useful features too. I just want to prevent it from automatically checking for library updates(If that's the problem shown above).

I included some part of my `dependencies` in `gradle` here:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.2.+'
}
```

Comment: You can use explicit version of library, like: 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'

It will be prevent your exception and speed up build.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies with a plus like `11.2.+'` will always lead to repeated builds.

You have to specify the full version like:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0
```

If you do not specify gradle will always be building because its looking for the latest version online of `11.2.+` may be `11.2.4`, `11.2.6` etc

Comment: I changed all 11.2.+ to 11.2.0. But it is still trying to sync them using network connection! @Xenolion

Comment: Actually the latest is `11.8.0` from https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_18_2017_-_version_1180  but you are also encouraged to use fcm instead of gcm. firebase is the deal these days. It will sync only once.